# displaying a pdf on a windows form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pdf

in vb.net is it possible to display a pdf file on a form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick hack for this would be to use a WebBrowser control (assuming the client has Adobe Reader installed) and navigate it to the PDF file you want to display.

Comment: cool suggestion, but the thing is i will need to place images on top of the pdf

Comment: Put the images in PictureBoxes, and put the PictureBoxes over the WebBrowser control. I think the WebBrowser has a Controls collection, and if it doesn't you just add the PictureBoxes to the form's Controls collection and call BringToFront on them.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking to display a PDF without needing Acrobat Reader installed on a client machine, take a look at this:

[PDF Viewer Control Without Acrobat Reader Installed](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/PDFViewerControl.aspx)

I haven't tried it yet but probably will.

Comment: +1 I like it, but I'd personally be a bit wary of having to deploy that many third-party DLLs along with my app. Not that my solution is much better.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that the client has Adobe Reader installed, nor that they have PDF viewing in the web browser enabled. What's more, if they don't, it's a hefty download. What's worse, a few third-party DLLs or one humongous dependency? Which will the user be less affected by?

Answer (score -4):

yes, but you will end up using a COM+