# Viewing a EmbeddedResource PDF in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pdf

Yes, this question has been asked before, but I don't feel there's been a good enough answer, or a solution I can relate to.

Leading from this question - [Displaying a PDF on a Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324601/displaying-a-pdf-on-a-windows-form), I'd like to display a PDF in a WebBrowser Control, but I'd like the PDF to be an EmbeddedResource.

This question - [Describing res protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254605/ms-webbrowser-embedded-html-resource-res-protocol) - is along the right lines I think, but neither the question nor the answer were voted up, and I could not get the solution to work.

Does anyone have a solution for viewing an EmbeddedResource PDF in a VB.NET Form? Either by following the steps described above with a little more detail - or another, better option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, the `res` protocol gives access to Win32 *native* resources.

.NET EmbeddedResource files are not stored as Win32 native resources. Therefore, the `res` protocol won't help you there.

Why don't your program simply make a temp copy of the PDF file and point the embedded browser to that file?

Edit: The only alternative I can think of is implementing your own [Pluggable Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916%28VS.85%29.aspx). But this is totally overkill and no serious mind would truly consider it ;-)

Comment: Yep, looks like that is the way I will have to go. 

Is there any way you can think of without streaming it to a temporary copy though?

Comment: Woarrrgggh @ Edit - I didn't even know that sort of stuff existed. However, it may be a little beyond me as of yet.

Comment: Serge, although the answer didn't have a huge amount of detail - it pointed me in the right direction.